# Trouble with saving date value using cakephp 1.2.5

Tags: cakephp

We have trouble with save() function when we use

```
<?php echo $form->input('columnname',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'date','div'=>false));?>.
```

After click submit button, it constructs sql statement to save the record. But the sql did not construct the date value but only recognize it as Array. Therefore, the data cann't be saved for error 1054:Unknown 'Array' in 'field list'. The same thing happends with type 'time'. How can we use the form help for saving date or time? And I am not sure where to look for the save() function for constructing the sql statement. Please help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please combinde date array to a string like this

```
function add(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $saveData   =   $this->data[$this->modelClass];     
        $date       =   $this->data[$this->modelClass]['month'].'/'.$this->data[$this->modelClass]['day'].'/'.$this->data[$this->modelClass]['year'];
        $saveData['date']   =   $date;
        $this->{$this->modelClass}->save($saveData);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tony! Can you kindly let me know where should I change this ? When call the save($saveData), it will save all the records

Comment: Thanks Tony! Can you let  me know where to change this? When the save($this->savedata) called in the controller, the sql constructed is wrong.

Comment: This should be in controller -> function  where you are posting the form. i have modified answer

Comment: In the controller, it is using $this->controllerobjectname->save($this->data). It's not only the date record but also with other records when it's constructing the sql statement. I can echo the date with implode('-', $this->data['controllerobjectname']['date']), but I don't know where I can replace the Array in the constructed sql statement.

Comment: Hi Tony, I see what your suggestion now. Before calling save function, replace the existing date value in the controller. That's a lot of work to do,but it's working! Thanks a lot!